# Java Arrays, Collections, Sets and Maps fit into the category of  xx objects?

Tags: java

Is it fair to group the following:

```
Arrays, Collections, Sets, Maps
```

into a group called Collections or is there another single word or two words (other than object) that best describes Arrays, Collections, Sets and Maps.

Sorry if this is not the right category or not a suitable question. I am learning about these topics and need to find a single word that best describes all of these.

Answer (score 2):

Collections sound fine. Data Structures also sound equally good.

Comment: Thanks. Hope to also get some more suggestions but Data Structures does sound good as it does not repeat the word Collections.

Comment: "Arrays, Collections, Sets, and Maps" are analogous to "Dogs, Cats, Animals and Fish". Data Structure is technically correct, but in the "Animals" analogy, it might be equivalent to saying "Organism"

Comment: @Ajay - What other java objects would you say fit under the category of Data Structures? Anything else that I missed?

Comment: A Data Structure is a pretty generic term. You can view the entire list here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures

Answer (score 1):

As the Java Reference Docs can tell you, [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), [Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) are all part of the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html). Thus not only are those three generally varieties of collections, but they are formally defined as such by Java.

Comment: So would it be best to divide this into 4 groups: Arrays, Sets, Maps and Collections? With the latter describing things common to sets and maps?

Comment: this isn't really a question with a "correct" answer. without knowing your specific context, it's hard to say exactly. from your wording, I get the impression that it's a homework/assignment-type question? in which case Data Structure is indeed a word that describes the four items. but as some have pointed out, it's not a very useful description.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Set` extends `Collection`, so it's not a new category unto itself.

If you look at the class hierarchy you'll see just two categories: `Collection` and `Map`. The latter has keys separate from values; the former does not.

Comment: Thanks duggymo. What do you think about "Data Structures"?

Comment: Too generic - it conveys no new information, because both are already known to be data structures.

Answer (score 0):

look on the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of collection. you will see that map is not extend interface collection, so data structure is better.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and Collections are classes with all static methods to help manipulating arrays of primitives,classes and the later for classes implementing Map,List,Set.

Ex: Collections sort()(takes comparator to sort different classes),addAll,freq or Arrays asList,sort,binarysearch

Comment: So would you say other things such as enums could go in the same group? I am looking for words that would help a user when learning. For example as part of the chapter of a booklet.